# Cannot use import statement outside a module (at index.js:1:1)

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

I have recently started learning JS, and I am trying to export a function from a module script to my main 'index.js' script. But I am "getting Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module (at index.js:1:1)" error.

Could someone please help me out?

I have tried using type = module. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I have tried running the code in chrome and edge both, same error.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <script src="./shoppingCart.js" type="module"></script>
  <script defer src="./index.js"></script>
  <title>Modern JavaScript Development: Modules and Tooling</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Modern JavaScript Development: Modules and Tooling</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

index.js

```
import * as shoppingCart from "./shoppingCart.js";
shoppingCart.addToCart("iPhone", 1);
```

shoppingCart.js

```
export const addToCart = function (product, quantity) {
  console.log(`${quantity} ${product} added to the cart.`);
};
```

Comment: _"I have tried using type = module"_ Your code should work with `type="module"`. Your code definitely won't work without `type="module"` - unless you use dynamic `import()` and `then()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only use `import` inside an ES Module.

Since you're using `import` inside `index.js`, you need to tell the browser that it is also a module (as well as `shoppingCart.js`).

Therefore, you need to add `type="module` to the `src` element that loads your index file.